# Set where clause basis parameter value in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, if-statement, where-clause

I wish to set a condition while making use of the WHERE clause basis @USER_ID input recorded from the user in my SQL server query, but I guess I am missing something essential here.

```sql
DECLARE @USER_ID NVARCHAR(255) = 'a,b,c' -- will be multi-select parameter; can be null as well 


select * from <table_name>

{
if:      @USER_ID is NULL then no WHERE condition
else:    WHERE <table_name>.<col_name> in (SELECT item FROM SplitString(@USER_ID,','))
}
```

Can someone please help here?

Comment: Have a read of [Revisiting catch-all queries](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2018/03/13/revisiting-catch-all-queries/)

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would suggest switching to a table type parameter, then you don't need to use `STRING_SPLIT` at all. I'm not going to cover the creation of said type of parameter here though; there's plenty already out there and the documentation is more than enough to explain it too.

As for the problem, if we were to be using `STRING_SPLIT` you would use a method like below:

```sql
SELECT {Your Columns} --Don't use *
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
WHERE YT.YourColumn IN (SELECT SS.Value
                        FROM STRING_SPLIT(@USER_ID,',') SS)
   OR @USER_ID IS NULL
OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

The `RECOMPILE` in the `OPTION` clause is important, as a query where `@USER_ID` has the value `NULL` is likely to be very different to that where it isn't.

You *could* use a dynamic SQL approach, but for one parameter, I doubt there will more anything more than a negligible benefit. Using the above is much easier for others to understand as well, and the cost of generating the plan every time the query is run should be tiny for such a simple query.

Using a table type parameter, it would actually likely be more performant (assuming you have a useable index on `YourColumn`) to use a `UNION ALL` query like the below:

```sql
SELECT {Your Columns} --Don't use *
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     JOIN @Users U ON YT.YourColumn = U.UserId
UNION ALL
SELECT {Your Columns} --Don't use *
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @Users U);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid using `STRING_SPLIT` entirely here:

```sql
WHERE ',' + @USER_ID + ',' LIKE '%,' + <table_name>.<col_name> + ',%'
```

Comment: Wouldn't `STRING_SPLIT` at least be SARGable though, where as the above would not?

Comment: @Larnu Good catch, but `STRING_SPLIT` involves generating an on-the-fly table-valued function results, which must also have its own overhead.

Comment: Yes, I will admit that a Table Type Parameter would likely be the *best™* solution.

Comment: I would have thought string_split would be much more performant, the one-off overhead of building the table of values would be neglegible to the IO cost of scanning an index as opposed to seeking directly to a subset of rows

Answer (score 0):

If the @UserID is NULL, then the condition (1=1) is executed, this is always true. If the @UserID is not NULL, then the OR condition is executed in which all <col_name> in (a, b, c) are present.

```
SELECT * 
FROM <table_name>
WHERE (1=1)
    AND ((@USER_ID IS NULL AND (1=1)) -- always true
        OR (<table_name>.<col_name> in (SELECT [value] FROM SplitString(@USER_ID,',')))
    )
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.